# Help with proof in Griffiths QM book

Tags: quantum-mechanics, integration

[image]

[image]

So, I'm having trouble with this proof in Griffiths' QM text. I don't get how Griffiths exactly goes from the text(circled in read) on page 47 to the next step(also circled in red). He says that he uses integration by parts, but I still can't work out how he uses that to get to the next step. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Please [do not post images of texts you want to quote](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10563), but type it out instead so it is readable for all users and so that it can be indexed by search engines. For formulae, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) instead.  Use the occasion to highlight the conceptual core of your question.

Comment: This may be more appropriate on a math forum. Rather than discussing a physics concept, an answer would just include the explanation  of the book's math.

Comment: @Chair no, math questions in the context of physics problems are accepted here.

Comment: @KyleKanos I guess you would know a lot better than me :) But I have seen a lot of posts migrated for that reason... Is there a meta post about this subject? I'll need to read it.

Comment: @Chair https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5713/25301

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The operator which is swapped from g to $f^*$ has the following form:

$\overbrace{\mp \hbar \frac{d}{dx}}^{A} + \overbrace{m\omega x}^{B}$

A is a differential operator, the second part B is just a number. So we can write

\begin{align}
\int f^{*} (A+B) g &= \int f^*Ag + \int f^*Bg\\ &= \int-A f^{*}g + \int Bf^{*} g \\ &= \int (-A +B) f^{*}g\end{align}

When $A$ is swapped from $g$ to  $f^*$, partial integration is applied as already remarked by Griffith, here is assumed that the term at the border of the integration area is zero (which is the case as $f$ and $g$ must go to zero at infinity, otherwise all the here discussed integrals would not exist). Application of the partial integration generates the minus sign.

When $B$ is swapped from $g$ to  $f^*$, we take into account that $B$ is just a number and multiplication is as generally known commutative.

$-A + B = \pm \hbar\frac{d}{dx} + m\omega x$

which corresponds to the expression in the second equation marked with red pen.